# Simulate vectors with some peculiar correlations in R

Tags: r, simulation

I want to simulate some data with the following restrictions:

```
    cor(x1, x2) == 0.00001 # close to 0
    cor(y1, x1) == 0.00001 # close to 0
    cor(y1, x2) == 0.00001 # close to 0
    cor(y2, x1) == 0.00001 # close to 0
    cor(y2, x2) == 0.00001 # close to 0
    cor(y1 + y2, x1 + x2) == 0.99999 # close to 1
```

All variables in use are vectors. 
How can this be done? Thanks!

---

This is not a duplicate of the question mentioned by several persons. I am not asking how to generate random numbers from a specific distribution, but rather how to generate groups of numbers with a special relationship with each other in terms of correlation. Please remove the duplicate mark.

Comment: No rules about the mean, variance, or general distribution of these four RVs?  Can you give us some background as to the real-world situation this relates to?

Comment: The real-world situation is genotype and compound genotype data. The distribution of these RVs does not concern me at the moment, I just want to simulate this scenario for the analysis of false association.

Comment: And since uncorrelated does not imply independent, are your RVs independent?

Comment: They may or may not be, depending on the distance between the bases.

Answer (score 1):

I think that this is not possible due to the link between the different variables and because the covariance of the sum of various random variables is equal to :[image: Covariance]

Answer (score 0):

A possible place to start:

http://books.google.com/books?id=irKSXZ7kKFgC&pg=PR14&lpg=PR14&dq=sum+uncorrelated+RV+to+get+correlation&source=bl&ots=tY-EggvkoS&sig=X7b75ijxpNI0Al52Zggn3WzhKZs&hl=en&sa=X&ei=952kUZTuCYXs9ATKrICwCA&ved=0CFQQ6AEwBg#v=onepage&q=sum%20uncorrelated%20RV%20to%20get%20correlation&f=false
(page 70)